# T-SQL CONTAINS and CONTAINSTABLE and punctuation like the period / dot

Tags: sql-server-2012, full-text-search, contains, containstable

Is there a way to make full-text search in SQL Server 2012 a little more "naive", removing the "intelligence" that causes it to treat the [.] character as a word separator?

We have meaningful strings that contain dots and want to treat the entire string as a contiguous token, not as separate chunks.

Is there a place where such "punctuation" marks are defined, which can be easily edited to remove the "."?